# DialogFlow python API return empty list values

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm using python API(V2) for dialogflow from https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2.

I have used "detect_intent_texts" method for getting response from dialogflow.

In response.query_result.parameters, I'm getting empty list_value. How can I get list type value in the response, I'm getting string values comfortably but not list values.

Comment: Could you please post the JSON that you see in the response?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happening when the agent is created thru api.

You may do one of the two below as a work around:

Option 1. Open the intent that is returning empty parameters and just save the intent once. Agent will start the training and after a few seconds will complete training

Option 2: Make the parameter mandatory (especially if you are creating the intent/agent thru api call) in the Action and Parameter session while creating the intent

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are matching the 'Training phrases' with correct 'entities' and IS LIST option should be checked.

[image]